# how to assign labels of one numpy array to another numpy array and group accordingly?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have the following labels

```
>>> lab
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

I want to assign this label to another numpy array i.e

```
>>> arr
array([[81,  1,  3, 87],  # 2
       [ 2,  0,  1,  0],  # 2
       [13,  6,  0,  0],  # 2
       [14,  0,  1, 30],  # 2
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],  # 2
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],  # 3
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],  # 3
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],  # 0
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],  # 0
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],  # 0 
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],  # 0
       [13,  2,  0, 11]]) # 1
```

and add the elements of 0th group, 1st group, 2nd group, 3rd group?

Answer (score 1):

If the labels of equal values are contiguous, as in your example, then you may use [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html):

```
>>> lab
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
>>> idx = np.r_[0, 1 + np.where(lab[1:] != lab[:-1])[0]]
>>> np.add.reduceat(arr, idx)
array([[110,   7,   5, 117],   # 2
       [  0,   0,   0,   0],   # 3
       [  0,   0,   0,   0],   # 0
       [ 13,   2,   0,  11]])  # 1
```

if they are not contiguous, then use [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to align the array and labels such that labels of the same values are next to each other:

```
>>> i = np.argsort(lab)
>>> lab, arr = lab[i], arr[i, :] # aligns array and labels such that labels
>>> lab                          # are sorted and equal labels are contiguous
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3])
>>> idx = np.r_[0, 1 + np.where(lab[1:] != lab[:-1])[0]]
>>> np.add.reduceat(arr, idx)
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0],  # 0
       [ 13,   2,   0,  11],  # 1
       [110,   7,   5, 117],  # 2
       [  0,   0,   0,   0]]) # 3
```

or alternatively use [`groupby` from pandas library](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(arr).groupby(lab).sum().values
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0],
       [ 13,   2,   0,  11],
       [110,   7,   5, 117],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0]])
```

Comment: Or with `np.diff` : `idx = np.append(0,np.nonzero(np.diff(lab))[0]+1)`.

Comment: But this code with np.diff is not working for lab=[1, 1, 1, 0, 1 ,2, 3 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,2]

Comment: @Aparna Yeah `np.diff` one is only for the case when the labels are consecutive.

Comment: Is there any other method if the labels are not consecutive?